# How to send a query to another website page and find a .length value that i can then import to my website

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display on my webpage how many customer reviews there are, however the customer reviews are on another website.

So my idea was to target the DOM of that website and find out how many reviews there are by using .length, which returns me the correct value.

but I need to somehow link that .length value to my own website so that people who view it can see in text how many reviews there are. there will be a hyperlink below this to then direct the viewer to the other site to read them.

I want this because every time someone leaves an additional review on the other website the .length value will change and therefore need this to reflect automatically on my website.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: I think you can do it with an IFrame. But I don't know if this is the best solution. Also what happens when this site change it's elements (or names). Then this will break. Isn't there an API that you can use?

Comment: Hi M1sterPl0w, this is my first website if i am honest, and haven't worked with any APi other than trying to use fetch and DOMparser in javascript. i agree to the problem regarding changing element names but this site has been collecting reviews for a long time and its never changed its structure, im happy to take the risk.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp